# Fix a custom order issue in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce shop and everything is up to date. I have a problem when I try to add a manual order into the backend of Woocommerce. This is the error:

[image]

This happens when I enter something in the "Add products" to the order. So I think there is some issue with the selectWoo.full.min.js file.

I tried to disable other plugins but that didnt help at all. Still had the same issue.

Comment: Which are the plugins you are using

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to show your errors, copy the text out and add it here instead.

Comment: This is a Javascript error that can be caused by your theme, by some plugins or by your own customizations. If it's a bug from Woocommerce plugin, you should better contact dedicated support threads instead.